# Нужно выполнить поиск в массиве строк пустых элементов и вернуть количество вхождений пустых строк

Tags: c#

Нужно вернуть количество вхождений пустых строк.

 Вот мой код

А вот тест (прикрепил)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static int GetEmptyStringCount(string[] arrayToSearch)
        {
            if (arrayToSearch is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
            }

            if (arrayToSearch.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int idx = 0;
            int countEmpyStr = 0;
            while (idx <= arrayToSearch.Length - 1)
            {
                countEmpyStr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayToSearch[^1]) ? 1 : 0;
                idx++;
            }

            return countEmpyStr;
        }
```

2 теста валит, хотя вроде всё правильно...

Comment: "вроде всё правильно" - `[^1]` - это что?

Comment: @Igor оператор индекса с конца

Comment: "оператор индекса с конца" - что значит эта фраза?

Comment: @Igor то, что чтение массива начинается не с 0 элемента, а с последнего, до 0-го

Comment: @Igor то есть мне нужно делать не idx++, а idx--? К этому клоните? И изменить условие, где будет ```idx >= 0```, в свой черед idx будет равен длине массива, так получается?

Comment: @Igor затупил, я до этого делал такие же задачи, там цикл for был и переменная была i, а я вместо idx сюда i вставлял ошибка была ))) 
спасибо за наводку мысли, вот рабочий код ```countEmpyStr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayToSearch[idx]) ? 1 : 0;```

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int GetEmptyStringCount(string[] array)
    {
        if (array == null) 
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
        if (array.Length == 0) 
           return 0;
        var count = array.Count(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

К чему такие трудности в вашем методе? Если вам нужно просто посчитать количество пустых строк - то используйте Linq:

```
private static int GetEmptyStringCount(string[] array)
{
    if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(array));

    return array.Count(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
}
```

Comment: Вторая проверка покрывает целиком первую, если что )

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет, если я попытаюсь обратиться к `array.Length`, но при этом `array == null`, то я получу `NullReferenceException`, а выкидывать хочу `ArgumentException`. Хотя это и не критично, наверное, даже стоило бы сделать 2 `if`'а. Один с `ArgumentNullException`, а второй просто с `ArgumentException`

Comment: Да нет, я про `IsNullOrEmpty` и  `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Писал тогда с телефона, неудобно было названия копипастить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Понял, согласен с Вами, изменил немного ответ.

Comment: @AlAvenger LINQ здесь нельзя использовать, я уже решил задачу, ответ дам.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetEmptyStringCount(string[] arrayToSearch)
        {
            if (arrayToSearch is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
            }

            if (arrayToSearch.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int idx = 0;
            int countEmpyStr = 0;
            while (idx <= arrayToSearch.Length - 1)
            {
                countEmpyStr += string.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayToSearch[idx]) ? 1 : 0;
                idx++;
            }

            return countEmpyStr;
        }
```

Comment: Лучше `idx < arrayToSearch.Length`. Проверка длины на 0 выглядит лишней. И вместо тернарщины лучше использовать обычный `if`.